# Show that a Ring Homomorphism doesn't exist

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

> I have been asked to show that there exists no ring homomorphism
>   $$h:\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-3)\,.$$

I notice that in the domain $x^2\equiv 2$ and in the range $x^2\equiv 3$. 
I have tried looking at $h(y)$ which must be of the form {$ax+b: a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$} and then considered $h(y^2)=h(2)$ but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If $1$ is sent to $1$, then we know that $2$ is sent to $2$. The domain has an element whose square is $2$, but you can verify that the range does not. Therefore any potential homomorphism couldn't be injective. However, the domain is a field, and every ring homomorphism where the domain is a field is injective. Therefore no homomorphism can exist.

Comment: The two rings in question are the fields $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3\,)$. As you point out, these fields are not isomorphic, and a ring homomorphism would have had to be an isomorphism., no go.

Comment: @Lubin not necessarily, it could be an isomorphism with a proper subfield (unless you're using Herstein's definition of isomorphism, which I seem to recall doesn't require it to be surjective, though I haven't cracked open the book in years).

Comment: Oh, I guess I should have rung in a dimension argument, too.

Comment: @MattSamuel could you, perhaps, explain why us knowing that 1 goes to 1 means that 2 goes to 2?

Comment: @New $2=1+1$ and it's a homomorphism.

Comment: @Ahh, sorry for wasting your time...